# How to unregister Apptentive in Android?

Tags: apptentive

I need to disable Apptentive from showing its feedback dialogs because it is interfering with my UI tests. I could not find any method to unregister or disable it.
I tried setting random app key like this, but apptentive is using the cached API key.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
  Apptentive.register(CustomApp.getInstance(), "");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unregister Apptentive after it has been registered, but there are a few ways to keep it from showing up when you run your UI tests.

1. Use a special build variant for your UI tests. Then, in `Application.onCreate()`, wrap the call to `Apptentive.register()` in a check against the build config flavor

   ```
   @Override
   onCreate() {
     if (!BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("<YOUR_UI_TEST_FLAVOR>")) {
       Apptentive.register(...);
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can set a piece of Custom Person Data like `Apptentive.addCustomPersonData("ui_test", true)`. Then, use that in your Interaction "Who" criteria so that the Interaciton can't show as long as this flag is true.